# How to implement Role Based Access Control with rails/java?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, authentication, authorization, rbac

I'm working on new application with many users, a few roles and specific permissions for those roles. I would like to know the best practices to implement RBAC.

My requirements are:

I will have set of roles assigned to users say,

```
user1=superadmin, user2=admin, user3=expert
```

Based on user role I have to restrict:

```
1. Html pages (links in home page).

2. Data in all pages. (like some level of data abstraction).

3. Html elements in few pages. (for eg: some buttons, labels..etc., will be visible to user3).
```

Is there a framework to go ahead with?

Any advise is very appreciated!

**NOTE:** We will using either rails/java to develop app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [cancan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). An (older) railscast can be found [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)

Example from github:

```
<% if can? :create, Project %>
  <%= link_to "New Project", new_project_path %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank for your reply. But will cancan support html elements restriction in each page?

Comment: @Oliver Added an example in the original post. You can check the users ' permission in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Casbin: https://casbin.org/

It supports Java and Javascript to do frontend and backend authorization.

Answer (score 0):

in this period I've created a new Open Source project related the RBAC:

[microservice-rbac-user-management](https://github.com/andreagiassi/microservice-rbac-user-management)

You can find an RBAC apis and model here ready to use and with all the documentation.
I hope this will help you.